# Repeatedly sample and combine elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose we have a list `L = ['a', 'b', 'c']`, I would like to perform a group sampling of `L` to generate an expected result:

```py
[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

We can see, in this final output, a list of lists, its each element, there are no repeated elements without considering the order. How to implement it in Python?

Comment: You got downvotes because you need to show us what was your attempt and what problems are you facing? Itertools module have some handy functions for that.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used the module of itertools much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is using `combinations` from `itertools` module. Do it in a for loop and change its `r=` parameter every time. `r=1`, `r=2`, until `r=len(L)`:

```py
from itertools import combinations

lst = ["a", "b", "c"]
print([list(item) for i in range(1, len(lst) + 1) for item in combinations(lst, i)])
```

output:

```
[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: Of course you could have it as a generator instead...